# Probabilty of Elements being smaller than a specific value

Tags: complexity-theory, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

Right now i am looking at the following statement, but i cant grasp why it is correct.
Can somebody help?
"If we look at F0 uniformly distributed (and, say, pairwise independent) elements of
[0, 1], we expect about t of them to be smaller than t/F0."

Kind Regards,
Ilian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining indicator random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{F_0}$ such that

$$
X_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if } x_i < \frac{t}{F_0} \\
0 \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}
$$

Then, we can count the number of elements $< \frac{t}{F_0}$ as follows

$$
[ \text{# of Elements} < \frac{t}{F_0} ]= \sum_{i=1}^{F_0} X_i
$$

Thus,

$$
\mathbb{E} [\text{# of Elements} < \frac{t}{F_0}] = \mathbb{E} [\sum_{i=1}^{F_0} X_i] \\
= \sum_{i=1}^{F_0} \mathbb{E}[X_i]
$$

By linearity of expectation. Note that by virtue of $X_i$'s being indicator random variables, and independently identically distributed, we have that

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}[X_i=1] + 0 \cdot \mathbb{P}[X_i=0] = \frac{t}{F_0}
$$

For all $1 \leq i \leq F_0$. Substituing, we get that

$$
\mathbb{E} [\text{# of Elements} < \frac{t}{F_0}] = \sum_{i=1}^{F_0} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{F_0} \frac{t}{F_0} = t
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you cut the interval in 5 pieces of length 1/5 and pick one then you would expect an element drawn uniformly at random to have chance 1/5 to belong to it. So for, say t =3, an interval of length 3/N the chance is 3/N. Hence you would expect 3 out of N draws to belong to it. Apply this to the interval with boundary 0 and 3/N.

Comment: Also to you: Thank you very much!